# Contenteditable not working with contententeditable span inside set to false

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I have a problem with the contenteditable div which I have replicated in jsfiddle. The problem is when I click in between the contenteditable div and hit backspace all the span tag inside the div is deleted. I tried it the same in the fiddle but it works normal. But when I place the cursor at the end it is deleting the span one by one.

This works

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<span contenteditable="false">value1</span>
<span contenteditable="false">value2</span>
<span contenteditable="false">value3</span>
<span contenteditable="false">value4</span>
<span contenteditable="false">value5</span>
<span contenteditable="false">value6</span>
</div>
<br/>
```

and this is not

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="formulaBox"  role="button" tabindex="0">
<span style="color: red;" contenteditable="false">SUM</span>
<span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">(</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 126, 255);" contenteditable="false">value1</span><span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">+</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 126, 255);" contenteditable="false">value2</span><span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">+</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 126, 255);" contenteditable="false">value3</span><span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">*</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 126, 255);" contenteditable="false">value4</span><span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">)</span>
<span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">/</span>
<span style="color: blue;" contenteditable="false">AVG</span>
<span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">(</span>
<span style="color: rgb(0, 126, 255);" contenteditable="false">value5</span><span style="color: black;" contenteditable="false">)</span>
</div>
```

Refer the below link
https://jsfiddle.net/9ruwpyv5/

The 1st div is replicated and the second is the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I just added a space in between all the span tag and it solved the issue.

```
$('#formulaBox span').before(" ");
```